# Program that builds a triangle made of asterisks

Tags: python

This is an exact copy of the one showed in the book Starting out with Python.

```
base_size = 8

def main():

    for r in range(base_size):
        for c in range(r + 1):
            print('*')
        print()

main()
```

Yet it doesnt give the correct answer:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
********
```

This is the output of the program, prints each * in a new line. So whats exactly wrong?

```
*

*
*

*
*
*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
base_size = 8

def main():

    for r in range(base_size):
        for c in range(r + 1):
            print('*',sep=" ",end="")
        print()

main()
```

maybe you can try to insert (sep=" ",end="") in your code in the last.
hope I can help you

or you can try the easier one
for example:

```html
base_size = 8

def main():

    for r in range(1,(base_size)):
        print("*"*r)

main()
```

Comment: For some reason it gives me a synthax error when using sep and end, I am using Python 2 btw.

Comment: Interesting, your second code works, althought the autor wants me to do a nested loop. This one does work.

Comment: If you use Python 2 you must put `from __future__ import print_function` at the top of your script for this to work.  Or you can change the code to just `print '*',` (note trailing comma) in Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

Because `print` outputs what you tell it to *plus* a newline. If you want to output characters *without* a newline, you need to do it slightly differently.

Python 3 allows you to specify the terminator for the `print` function:

```
base_size = 8
def main():
    for r in range(base_size):
        for c in range(r + 1):
            print('*', end="")
        print()
main()
```

But, if you're using Python 2, you can just use:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write('*')
```

for equivalent behavior, as in:

```
import sys
base_size = 8
def main():
    for r in range(base_size):
        for c in range(r + 1):
            sys.stdout.write('*')
        sys.stdout.write('\n')
main()
```